# How to get href title from a element and delete all string?

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the title of links from a webpage. The links may look like

```
< a href="http://xxxx">Some text< /a>
```

or

```
< a href="http://xxxx"><div> < image> < /image> < div> < /a>
```

there maybe other link which u can image, but the most common two I have is as these two. I add some space to let the page do not consider it as link.

I need to get all the `some text` part. `msg` is the code of a webpage. I have wrote the code as

```
titleregex=re.compile('<a\s*href="http.*?[\'"].*?>(.+?)</a>')
titles = titleregex.findall(str(msg))
```

The code sucefully dealing with the first type link but not the second type. Any one can help me to delete all `<xxx>`?

Comment: What's your expected output? Did you want to delete or retrieve?

Comment: How about a logic, `if after` `>` you find `<` then ignore, but `if after` `>` you find something else get the character till you come across the character `<`

Comment: @AvinashRaj as I mention the I want get all the some text, which is the title of a url. BUt some time when I find a href, there is no "some text", but a image or other thing. I do not know how to get rid of them.

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/bR6fI0/1 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks, but the code it is wrong on my computer

Comment: I really like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4091324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes properly.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """< a href="http://xxxx"><div> < image> < /image> < div> < /a>
... < a href="http://xxxx">Some text< /a>"""
>>> re.findall(r"< a\s*href=['\"]http.*?['\"][^<>]*>([^<>]*)<\s*/a>", s)
['Some text']
```

OR

Seems like you're trying to remove all the tags.

```
>>> s = '< a href="http://xxxx">Some text< /a>'
>>> re.sub(r'<[^<>]*>', r'', s)
'Some text'
```

Comment: I do not work on my computer, how about just let me know how to delete all <xxx> as I asked?

Comment: use this regex `<[^<>]*>` and replace all the match with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

### Use this Pattern

```
href\s*=\s*\"*[^\">]*
```

And flag

```
re.IGNORECASE, re.I  
re.MULTILINE, re.M
```

---

Refere this <kbd>**[URL](http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0033.html)**</kbd> sure help you